# How to use the "For Loop" to close multiple buy and sell positions with different pip values

Tags: c#, for-loop

How can I use the "For Loop" to write the following code to save lines in my coding? I have tried, but I got stuck at the ClosePosition(position); lines. (for using the word position) The "For Loop" must change the Pips and position values. I am a beginner - please help. See code below:

```
    // Block One 
foreach (var position in positions)
                if (position.TradeType == TradeType.Buy)
                    if (position.Pips > 22)
                    {
                        ClosePosition(position, 2200);
                    }
            foreach (var position in positions)
                if (position.TradeType == TradeType.Sell)
                    if (position.Pips > 22)
                    {
                        ClosePosition(position, 2200);
                    }

            // Block Two
            foreach (var position in positions)
                if (position.TradeType == TradeType.Buy)
                    if (position.Pips > 21)
                    {
                        ClosePosition(position, 2100);
                    }
            foreach (var position in positions)
                if (position.TradeType == TradeType.Sell)
                    if (position.Pips > 21)
                    {
                        ClosePosition(position, 2100);
                    }

            // Block Three
            foreach (var position in positions)
                if (position.TradeType == TradeType.Buy)
                    if (position.Pips > 20)
                    {
                        ClosePosition(position, 2000);
                    }
            foreach (var position in positions)
                if (position.TradeType == TradeType.Sell)
                    if (position.Pips > 20)
                    {
                        ClosePosition(position, 2000);
                    }
               

 

I have tried the following code, but it is not working.

protected override void OnBar()
        {
            var positions = this.Positions.FindAll("PerfectBot");
            double netProfit = positions.Sum(x => x.NetProfit);
            
            int[] position = new int[3] 
            {
                20,
                21,
                22
            };

            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i--)
                foreach (int value in position)
                    if (position[i].Contains(int value))
                    if (position.TradeType == TradeType.Sell)
                    if (position.Pips > 22)
                    {
                        ClosePosition(position, 2200);
                    }
}
```

I would like to use the code in the OnBar(); section - for using the different time frames.
I would appreciate your help. Have a lovely day.

Comment: please, mention the programming language that is used, it will help

Comment: In Microsoft C#. I would really, really appreciate your help.

Have a lovely day.

Comment: read about switch https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch

Comment: you can have only 1 for-loop... and in this loop you can do a check for `position.TradeType`

Comment: Is the order important? I mean, in the original code, you close **all** `TradeType == Buy` and `Pips > 22` positions before handling any `TradeType == Sell` positions or lower `Pips` values...

Comment: As a side-note, I would *strongly* encourage you to use braces for *all* loops and `if` statements, even if the body is only a single statement... and indent all the code accordingly. (Your three `if` statements at the bottom are nested, but the indentation doesn't make that clear.) You can get Visual Studio to reformat your code, indenting it appropriately.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of six `foreach` loops, each with a single `if` (with another `if` inside), you can combine those `if`s within a single foreach-loop. Plus I would suggest to always use `{ }` - it makes your code clearer.

```
foreach (var position in positions)
{
    if (position.TradeType == TradeType.Buy)
    {
        if (position.Pips > 22)
        {
             ClosePosition(position, 2200);
        }
        else if (position.Pips > 21)
        {
             ClosePosition(position, 2100);
        }
        else if (position.Pips > 20)
        {
             ClosePosition(position, 2000);
        }
    }

    if (position.TradeType == TradeType.Sell)
    {
        if (position.Pips > 22)
        {
            ClosePosition(position, 2200);
        }
        // else if ...
    }

    // etc
}
```

Next you could combine those nested `if`s:

```
    if (position.TradeType == TradeType.Buy && position.Pips > 22)
    {
        ClosePosition(position, 2200);
    }
```

Or you can use a `switch` within the foreach-loop:

```
   switch (position.TradeType)
   {
      case TradeType.Buy:
        if (position.Pips > 22)
        {
             ClosePosition(position, 2200);
        }
        break;
      case TradeType.Sell:
        if (position.Pips > 22)
        {
            ClosePosition(position, 2200);
        }
        break;
     // etc
   }
```

Using a recent C# version, you can make it even shorter:

```
   switch (position.TradeType)
   {
      case TradeType.Buy when position.Pips > 22:
         ClosePosition(position, 2200);
         break;
      case TradeType.Sell when position.Pips > 22:
         ClosePosition(position, 2200);
         break;
     // etc
   }
```

Comment: Wow!... Thank you so much. This was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the refactored code do mostly the same thing in the same order as your original code.

Helper function

```
private static int ResolvePips(int pips)
{
    if (pips > 22) return 2200;
    if (pips > 21) return 2100;
    if (pips > 20) return 2000;
    // whatever works in other cases?
    throw new ArgumentException(nameof(pips));
}
```

Since your actual `ClosePosition` signature is the same, no matter whether you buy or sell or what pips value occurs, you can pre-filter and pre-order your items and then just call `ClosePosition` with appropriate parameters. There is no need to have multiple lines of code that call `ClosePosition`.

```
var preparedPositions = positions
    // no idea what should happen with smaller pips...
    .Where(p => p.Pips > 20)
    // just in case there might be other trade types...
    .Where(p => p.TradeType == TradeType.Buy || p.TradeType == TradeType.Sell)
    // handle highest pips range first
    .OrderByDesc(p => ResolvePips(p.Pips))
    // handle buy before sell
    .ThenByDesc(p => p.TradeType == TradeType.Buy);

foreach (var position in preparedPositions)
{
    ClosePosition(position, ResolvePips(position.Pips));
}
```

Comment: I really, really like this one. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have received this error code in the foreach line. (Error CS0230: Type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement.) What should I do there?

Comment: @MustangSally Changed... I coded this in the browser, so I didn't get any warning when I forgot the `var` before the loop variable